# Is Vite/Svelte compatible with mongodb npm package or mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am trying to use Mongodb as the backend to a Svelte (Vite) (not Sveltekit) frontend.

I completed the demo provided by Mongodb [(NPM MongoDB Node.js Driver Tutorial | MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/javascript/mongodb-and-npm-tutorial)) which is vanilla js. This is the npm package mongodb (npm i mongodb). This worked fine. Updates locally with a local connection string (as long as mongod is running) and updates Atlas (cloud) with the cloud connection string (which does not need mongodb running locally). With that all working well, I decided to test the same with Svelte (vite).

So I created a new Svelte project (*npm init vite@latest nodemongo*) and used the code from the mongodb "demo" and started to hit problems like ..

*Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js?v=2be29d5a' does not provide an export named 'MongoClient'*

and

*emphasizedUncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
at Object. (browser.umd.js:220:314) text*

which have nothing to do with the code.

Next, I uninstalled the mongodb package and instead installed mongoose and tried again. Now I am hitting the same second error shown above.

Has anyone got a Vite (not Svelekit)/Mongodb app up and running and if so would you mind sharing the secret! (Im running on Windows 11/Node v16.14.9 Svelte 3.49.0 Vite 3.1.0 Mongoose 6.6.6)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an express server middleware which picks up the http requests from svelte app and handles the backend communication with mongodb.